# Mixing 〜し and 〜ので in an explanation

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

In the *Genki Chapter 13* reading section, an exchange student describes going to a restaurant with her host family and unwittingly eating turtle for the first time. Her host-father insists it is tasty. Despite feeling uneasy about eating the mystery meat, she writes:

> でも、お腹がすいた**し**、おいしかった**ので**、たくさん食べました。

What is happening with this mix of し and ので? It seems the ので clause has some sense of "and because it ended up being tasty", while the し clause seems to relate to her reasoning before she started eating.